# Gitlab CICD minutes insufficient?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

According to [gitlab.com](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2020/03/18/ci-minutes-for-free-users/), free CICD limit is 2000 minutes. Quoting their documentation:

"Moving forward, all free accounts will have 2000 pipeline minutes per group per month independent of the visibility of the project"

So if it is per group, can I get more CICD minutes if I create different groups and add projects there? Or is this limit is at account level? Can anyone please clarify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/subscriptions/#purchasing-additional-ci-minutes, if you hit the quota, you can purchase additional minutes for a group or for your personal namespace.  It sounds like there is a group quota, and an account quota.

Also, per the release announcement you mentioned ( https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2020/03/18/ci-minutes-for-free-users/), most people use less than 1,000 minutes.

Comment: Thanks Aleksey. The question is, under the same account, if I create two separate groups, will I get a total of 4000 minutes (2000 for each group) for free?

Comment: Thanks Aleksey. Their documentation is a bit misleading

Answer (score 2):

Update 2021: the official [documentation is here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/subscriptions/gitlab_com/index.html#ci-pipeline-minutes) (with [FAQ](https://about.gitlab.com/pricing/faq-consumption-cicd/))

> ### CI pipeline minutes
>
> CI pipeline minutes are the execution time for your pipelines on GitLab shared runners.
> Each GitLab SaaS tier includes a monthly quota of CI pipeline minutes for private and public projects in the namespace:

Note the minutes have been reduced from 2000 to... 400.

See:

> ### [Changes to GitLab.com public project CI/CD minute quotas](https://about.gitlab.com/blog/2021/11/11/public-project-minute-limits/)

From [Jackie Porter](http://Jackie%20Porter):

> In the upcoming milestones, we will be extending CI/CD minute usage quotas to non-[open source programs](https://about.gitlab.com/handbook/marketing/community-relations/opensource-program/) on GitLab.com public projects.
>
> In the first half of 2021, GitLab.com and other CI/CD providers faced a large uptick in the abuse of free pipeline minutes to mine for cryptocurrencies.
> To discourage and reduce abuse, we [announced](https://about.gitlab.com/blog/2021/05/17/prevent-crypto-mining-abuse/) several changes to help ensure service continued to be reliable for our customers and users. The most recent change was made on 2021-07-17 to "include public projects in pipeline minutes quota for free users."